# Using ARR as a reverse proxy with MVC routing enabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, arr

I've been attempting to setup a reverse proxy using ARR with little success until I finally started on a brand new blank site instead of my existing site.

It works, but what I found is that when attempting to setup url rewrite and ARR to reverse proxy, MVC's routing takes over and gums up the works.  If I disable all MVC routing rules for the site, the reverse proxy works as expected.

I have my routes defined in the web.config in the  section which works great, but I cannot figure out how to add an ignored route in the XML structure, only through code. I don't want to define it in code, since I'd have to modify and deploy the website anytime one of the reverse proxies change (which are not really 'related' to the site).

So, I can see two possible solutions:

1. Prevent MVC routing from intercepting/interfering with IIS URL rewrite rules
2. Add ignore routes into my web.config

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find how to implement either